# How long does it take for CBP to respond to I-94 amendment requests?

Tags: usa

According to [HuntonImmigrationLawBlog](https://www.huntonimmigrationlawblog.com/2015/04/articles/federal-agencies/cbp/cpb-now-offers-email-addresses-for-i94-correction-requests-at-some-deferred-inspection-sites/):

> Until recently, travelers were required to appear in person at a
>   Deferred Inspection site, with their original documents, in order to
>   request that an I-94 be corrected. CBP has updated its Deferred
>   Inspections Sites list to include email addresses for I-94 correction
>   requests at the following nine Deferred Inspection offices:
>
> 1. Boston:  cbp.boston.i94@cbp.dhs.gov
> 2. Charlotte:  i94request-clt@cbp.dhs.gov
> 3. Chicago:  i94chi@cbp.dhs.gov
> 4. Houston:  cbphoui94@cbp.dhs.gov
> 5. Miami:  cbpmiai94@cbp.dhs.gov
> 6. Milwaukee:  i94mil@cbp.dhs.gov
> 7. Orlando:  orlandoi-94team@cbp.dhs.gov
> 8. Seattle:  i94.correction.seattle@cbp.dhs.gov
> 9. St. Paul:  i94msp@cbp.dhs.gov

How long does it take CBP to respond to I-94 amendment requests in practice? Or perhaps they have an official ETA somewhere?

Comment: I am writing because the I94 of my last entry to the US does not appear for me to print out. The last time I entered was on November 20th, 2020. Is it possible for you to send it to me or let me know how to get it? Thanks so much, Beatriz Pardo de Suarez

Comment: @BeatrizPardodeSuarez we cannot send you an I-94 form because we are not an agency of the US government.  If you have a question about the I-94 system, please post it as a new question using the button at the top of the page or by clicking https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/ask, and we will try to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in one case, it took exactly **one week** for them to respond and update the I-94 to the expected status.